# PHP - remove white spaces before comma

Tags: php, trim

In PHP is there any way I remove spaces **before** comma, like:

```
echo function("Yes , okay. No , okay."), PHP_EOL;
```

to

```
echo function("Yes, okay. No, okay."), PHP_EOL;
```

I tried with `trim()`, but no effect?

Comment: Why would you even try to use `trim()`, which has a completely different purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "Yes , okay. No , okay.";
$output = preg_replace("/[ ]+,/", ",", $input);
echo $output;  // Yes, okay. No, okay.
```

Comment: That is not the output OP wants. You should replace with `,` and not empty string

Comment: @Justinas Yes, OK `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_replace` for that:

```
echo str_replace(' , ', ', ', "Yes , okay. No , okay."), PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple str replace would do the job

```
$string = "Yes , okay. No , okay.";
$stripped = str_replace(" ,", ",", $string);
```

Comment: what about `"Yes      , okay"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace here.

```
$str = "Yes , okay. No , okay.";
echo str_replace(' ,', ',', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
$string = str_replace(' ,', ',', $string);
```